# Why rvest can't see tables

Tags: r, rvest

I'm having problem trying to **scrape** tables' content from some page. This code shows 5 tables

```
page <- read_html('https://wybory.gov.pl/sejmsenat2019/pl/kandydaci/sejm/1')
 page %>% html_nodes('table')
```

when specifying more

```
page %>%
  html_nodes('div.con_can')
  html_nodes('table')
```

it drops to one table, while i can see there are at least 8 of them, all wrapped in `div.table-responsive`, but when trying to list them

```
page %>%
  html_nodes('div.table-responsive')
  html_nodes('table') %>%
```

I still get one table returned (`{xml_nodeset (1)}`) and it is not any of the visible tables that I'm interested in.

So the question is: how do I get all tables with candidates name / profession and affiliation on this page listed, and / or how to scrape them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer the question on why `rvest` is not able to download the tables, but using the `RSelenium` package, the following should work, but needs to be extended, to download all the tables. I would use a loop to dynamically adjust the number of the table and download it, but this should get you started.
Please make sure that the encoding is correct.

```
library(rvest)
library(data.table)
library(httr)
library(XML)
library(RSelenium)
library(dplyr)
mybrowser <- rsDriver(browser = 'firefox') 

link <- "https://wybory.gov.pl/sejmsenat2019/pl/kandydaci/sejm/1"
mybrowser$client$navigate(link)

mybrowser$client$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#DataTables_Table_0")$getElementText()

html.table.0 <-  mybrowser$client$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#DataTables_Table_0") 
html.table.1 <-  mybrowser$client$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#DataTables_Table_1") 
html.table.2 <-  mybrowser$client$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#DataTables_Table_2") 

webElem5txt.0 <- html.table.0$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]
webElem5txt.1 <- html.table.1$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]
webElem5txt.2 <- html.table.2$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]
df.table.0 <-  read_html(webElem5txt.0) %>% html_table() %>% data.frame(.)
df.table.1 <-  read_html(webElem5txt.1) %>% html_table() %>% data.frame(.)
df.table.2 <-  read_html(webElem5txt.2) %>% html_table() %>% data.frame(.)

mybrowser$server$stop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @hannes101. It seems the task is bigger than my R skills at the moment. I was hoping there is some simple 'rvest' solution which I'm not aware of...

Comment: You grow along with your tasks. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't see them because the content is dynamically retrieved from a call which returns a blob file.

[image]

> Request URL: https://wybory.gov.pl/sejmsenat2019/data/kk/sejm/1.blob
>
> Request Method: GET

whilst you can stream this, or in fact just grab in one go, you will need to deal with the encoding (with python the [codecs UTF-8-sig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) does a decent enough job); and then you will also need to handle the reconstruction of the tables format.

So, selenium here is possibly a good alternative if for a small project.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I wasn't even aware  of things like blob files, and thought I miss some simple rvest solution.